# Running thousands of commands

Tags: perl, shell, batch-file

I have a command that has to be run thousands of times, i.e.

```
command.exe -X="AAA"
command.exe -X="AAB"
...
command.exe -X="ZZZ"
```

It would go from AAA->ZZZ

Each command will return "Success" or "Failure". What is the most efficient way to make a program that will run all these commands in a format like

```
AAA: Success
AAB: Failure
...
```

My first idea was to generate a list of every uppercase alpha possibilities and then concatenate it with the command and paste it into a batch file but there must be an easier way to run this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost identical to [Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101065/176646) except that this will actually run the command and print the corresponding output:

```
for my $i ('AAA'..'ZZZ') {
    my $output = `command.exe -X="$i"`;
    print "$i: $output\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah wonderful this is what I needed!

How would I modify it to go from 000 to ZZZ?

Answer (score 4):

```
for my $i ('AAA'..'ZZZ') {
    print qq{command.exe -X="$i"}
}
```

Comment: That's half of the equation, but the OP also wants to run the commands and print out the status.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OP is primarily concerned with parameter generation.

Comment: @mpapec The OP says "What is the most efficient way to make a program **that will run all these commands**..."

Comment: and then he writes `My first idea was to generate a list of every uppercase alpha possibilities..`

Comment: @mpapec And that sentence ends with, "...but there must be an easier way to run this." But maybe the OP will tell us his or her thoughts directly.

Comment: (there's a missing `"` before `$i`)

Comment: We can't help much more without knowing how to distinguish a successful run of the command from a failure.

Answer (score 3):

For a pure batch option

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "r=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for /l %%n in (0 1 17575) do (
        set /a "a=%%n/676", "b=(%%n %% 676)/26", "c=%%n %% 26"
        for %%a in (!a!) do for %%b in (!b!) do for %%c in (!c!) do (
            set "X=!r:~%%a,1!!r:~%%b,1!!r:~%%c,1!"
            for /f %%x in ('command.exe -X="!X!"') do echo(!X!:%%x
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

> How would I modify it to go from 000 to ZZZ?

You'll nedd `Number::AnyBase` from [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~emazep/Number-AnyBase-1.50002/lib/Number/AnyBase.pm),

```
sub iter {
  my ($len, $start) = @_;
  $len   ||= 3;
  $start ||= 0;

  use Number::AnyBase;
  my $c = Number::AnyBase->new([ 0..9, 'A'..'Z' ]);
  my $end = $c->to_dec("Z" x $len);

  return sub {
    return if $start>$end;
    my $s = sprintf("%${len}s", $c->to_base( $start++ ));

    $s =~ s/ /0/g;
    return $s;
  };
}

my $it = iter();
while (my $i = $it->()) {
  my $output = `command.exe -X="$i"`;
  print "$i: $output\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure batch solution :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%a in (65,1,90) do for /l %%b in (65,1,90) do for /l %%c in (65,1,90) do call:# %%a %%b %%c
exit/b
:#
set $#=
for %%* in (%1 %2 %3) do (cmd /c exit %%*
                          set $#=!$#!!=exitcodeascii!)  
echo Treating : !$#!
for /f "delims=" %%z in ('command.exe -X="!$#!"') do echo !$#! : %%z
```